STM32MP157DK Yocto Busybox and i2cdetect error
I am current running a build of a custom image using Yocto and I am following the Digikey Tutorials, however I have been stuck with an error that is thrown after enabling i2cdetect. the error is as shown below

 Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "stm32mp1"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.33"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:63d05fc061006bf1a88630d6d91cdc76ea33fbf2"
meta-oe              
meta-python          = "dunfell:01358b6d705071cc0ac5aefa7670ab235709729a"
meta-st-stm32mp      = "dunfell:a8d55e2fe13d6be03222f45b3115a96938b2553a"
meta-custom          = "<unknown>:<unknown>"

WARNING: /home/raymond/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.31.1.bb:do_compile is tainted from a forced run                                                                      | ETA:  0:00:00
Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 22 Found 0 Missed 22 Current 1191 (0% match, 98% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: busybox-1.31.1-r0 do_package: Error executing a python function in exec_func_python() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_func_python() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:ptest_update_alternatives(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/raymond/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/classes/ptest.bbclass', lineno: 98, function: ptest_update_alternatives
     0094:        for alt_name, alt_link, alt_target, _ in alternatives:
     0095:            # Some alternatives are for man pages,
     0096:            # check if the alternative is in PATH
     0097:            if os.path.dirname(alt_link) in bin_paths:
 *** 0098:                os.symlink(alt_target, os.path.join(ptest_bindir, alt_name))
     0099:}
     0100:
     0101:do_configure_ptest_base[dirs] = "${B}"
     0102:do_compile_ptest_base[dirs] = "${B}"
Exception: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/bin/busybox.suid' -> '/home/raymond/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.31.1-r0/package/usr/lib/busybox/ptest/bin/i2cdetect'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/raymond/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.31.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.36688
ERROR: Task (/home/raymond/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.31.1.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'

I have tried adding
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = "i2c-tools"
to my custom image bb file, but this has not solved anything, I am still quite a beginner in Yocto, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Maybe a simple bitbake -c cleanall busybox will do?

@Schottky I have done so but still facing the same issue

Did you also delete the temp folder and build everything again?

I have just tried doing that, still facing the same issue. I really don't know what needs to be done now.

Could it be that the i2c-tools is already built by another recipe? What is the output of oe-pkgdata-util find-path /usr/sbin/i2cdetect.i2c-tools? Is it also an error? For me, this returns i2c-tools, but it might be possible that busybox has some of these tools as well and both try to populate the sysroot.,

I am getting this output ERROR: Unable to find any package producing path /usr/sbin/i2cdetect.i2c-tools, showing that the its not available or installed
